# npx serve is serving home directory instead of index.html

Tags: reactjs, azure-web-app-service, pm2, serve

My Web App Service running on Linux serves a React App which is has its build files in wwwroot, served using a pm2 process that runs npx serve:

ecosystem.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      script: "npx serve -s",
    },
  ],
};
```

This worked fine until serve randomly started serving the entire /home directory instead of the index.html file in the wwwroot. This is what the web page in the browser looks like now.

[image]

The pm2 process seems to be running fine.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had a bunch of sites go down today or this weekend with same issue.  I have a ticket in with M$ to understand why, but we were able to temporarily fix by using the startup command option in azure.

[App Service Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZa0h.png)

Comment: I have the same issue with a React app on App Service that's happened in the past few days. The suggested workaround in your answer worked for me. Thanks. If you get a response from MS please post an update.

Comment: I used a similar workaround, but my startup command switches to pm2, the --spa option is for client side routing `pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa`